# Android Listview displaying header when Overscrolled

Tags: android, listview

I need my Android Listview to display a Help screen as a header which will be displayed when the user over scrolled.

I tried using PulltoRefreshListView, But, i have a problem when the number of rows are less and the height is less than the list height. The header view is automatically displayed even before pulling it down.

I achieved this functionality very easily in 2.2 android version by using a small line of below code.

listview_object.setPadding(0,-height_of_the_header,0,0);

This piece of code is not working for 2.3 and above as the overscroll is locked in those versions.

Even there is a method like setOverscrollMethod(int) for 2.3 and above, but is not working.

Can someone help me to resolve this... ?

My requirement is just to display a help screen which will be coming from the top of the listview when user overscrolled from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this [widget](https://github.com/chrisbanes/android-pulltorefresh)

It will not shows header when lines' height is less than ListView's.

Comment: This one worked for me after doing lot of tweaks to the code. Any way thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I too am trying to achieve this - however I am struggling to get the pull to refresh widget linked here to work.. Pavandroid, is there any way you could share how you have done this? It would be a massive help if so...